# Having trouble reducing the total in this small todo app

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the the value from every new Li and reduce it (add) to then output to my h2. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Codepen: https://codepen.io/Chasehud26/pen/Poagjwy

I tried to console.log different variables to see if there were any hints of what is going wrong.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name-input")
const priceInput = document.querySelector("#price-input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
const nameUl = document.querySelector("#item-name")
const priceUl = document.querySelector("#item-price")
const h2 = document.querySelector("h2")

const nameLi = document.createElement("li")
const priceLi = document.createElement("li")


form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let nameVal = nameInput.value
    let priceVal = priceInput.value

    const nameLi = document.createElement("li")
    const priceLi = document.createElement("li")


    nameUl.appendChild(nameLi)
    nameLi.innerHTML = nameInput.value

    priceUl.appendChild(priceLi)
    priceLi.textContent = `${priceInput.value}`

    showTotals()
})


//TRYING TO ADD TOGETHER ALL THE PRICE VALUES AND THEN PUT IT TO MY H2//
function showTotals() {
    const priceList = document.querySelectorAll("li")

    for (let priceLists of priceList) {
        const total = []
        total.push(parseFloat(priceLists.textContent));
        const totalMoney = total.reduce(function (total, item) {
            total += item;
            return total;
        }, 0);

        const finalMoney = totalMoney.toFixed(2);
        h2.textContent = finalMoney;
    }
}
```

Comment: at each iteration of the loop iterating over the price list you are summing up all the values you have in total so far.. again and again. While you should maybe just populate the total array with each li content and only after the loop ended, sum those values. You are also updating the textContent of your h2 multiple times instead of once only. Anyway I'm not sure to get it right because it would too big of a mistake if it was how I see it

Comment: So, just looking through your codepen, your :     
`const nameLi = document.createElement("li")`
`const priceLi = document.createElement("li")` 
are both LI elements

So your method is trying to add items that are not numbers I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your `const total []` array initialized outside of the for loop. also, when you setup your `<li>` decorators, you need to differentiate between the number and non-number fields, since the way you had it, it was trying to add the text 'li' fields also:

```
/// truncated for clarity
const nameLi = document.createElement("li")
const priceLi = document.createElement("li")
priceLi.classList.add('num') // <== this line added
//// =================

function showTotals() {
    const priceList = document.querySelectorAll("li.num") // added class 
    const total = [] // <== move this to here
    for (let priceLists of priceList) {
      total.push(parseFloat(priceLists.textContent));
      const totalMoney = total.reduce(function (total, item) {
        total += item;
        return total;
    }, 0);

    const finalMoney = totalMoney.toFixed(2);
    h2.textContent = finalMoney;
}
```